# Multiple conditions with if/elif statements

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I'm trying to get an if statement to trigger from more than one condition without rewriting the statement multiple times with different triggers. e.g.:

```
if user_input == "look":  
    print description


if user_input == "look around":
    print description
```

How would you condense those into one statement?

I've tried using 'or' and it caused any raw_input at all to trigger the statement regardless of whether the input matched either of the conditions.

```
if user_input == "look" or "look around":  
    print description
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you're trying to do is

```
if user_input == "look" or user_input == "look around":
    print description
```

Another option if you have a lot of possibilities:

```
if user_input in ("look", "look around"):
    print description
```

Since you're using 2.7, you could also write it like this (which works in 2.7 or 3+, but not in 2.6 or below):

```
if user_input in {"look", "look around"}:
    print description
```

which makes a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) of your elements, which is very slightly faster to search over (though that only matters if the number of elements you're checking is much larger than 2).

---

The reason your first attempt always went through is this. Most things in Python evaluate to `True` (other than `False`, `None`, or empty strings, lists, dicts, ...). `or` takes two things and evaluates them as booleans. So `user_input == "look" or "look around"` is treated like `(user_input == "look") or "look_around"`; if the first one is false, it's like you wrote `if "look_around":`, which will always go through.

Comment: Thanks Dougal! Stupid question really!

Comment: @Blaine This is a problem that lots of new programmers run into in Python; it _looks_ like it's doing what you want it to do, but, well, it doesn't. :) Hopefully my explanation of why it operates like it does makes sense.

Comment: Ahhh that explains it. Been learning my logic tables so I get you! :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use regular expressions to match the strings if they follow a pattern with
optional sections or you could do an array lookup:

```
if user_input in ["look", "look around"]:
    print description
```

The boolean operator `or` only works with boolean values, it evaluates the expressions
on both sides and returns `True` if one of the expressions evaluates to `True`.
It has nothing to do with the natural language '