# Writing less elif statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I need help with this.

```
a = ["cat","dog","fish","hamster"]

 user = raw_input("choose your fav pet ")

if user == a[0]:

    print a[0]

elif user == a[1]:

    print a[1]

elif user == a[2]:

    print a[2]

elif user == a[3]:

    print a[3]

else:

    print "sorry, the aninimal you type does not exist"
```

What I want to do is a testing mobile app so I use animal as testing. The program did work but the problem is that there are over 100's of animals in the world and I put them in a list, I don't want to create many `elif` statements.

Is there a way to make it shorter and faster?

Comment: Is `if user in a: ...` what you seek? Then, you could simply print `user` as exactly this string is contained in your list `a` and you are done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple conditions with if/elif statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335382/multiple-conditions-with-if-elif-statements)

Answer (score 5):

Use a `for` loop:

```
for animal in a:
    if user == animal:
        print animal
        break
else:
    print "Sorry, the animal you typed does not exist"
```

I'd note however that this code is a bit silly. If all you're going to do when you find the animal matching the user's entry is print it, you could instead just check if the entry is in the `a` list and `print user` if it is:

```
if user in a:
    print user
else:
    print "Sorry, the animal you typed does not exist"
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with:

```
if user in a:
    print user
```

That will check if `user` input is in the list of pets and if it is, it will print it.

Comment: Or even `print(a.get(user, "sorry, the animal you type does not exist"))`

Comment: @csl: `a` is a list not a `dict`, so there is no `a.get` method to call.

Answer (score 0):

Use in operator:

```
if user in a:
    print user
else : 
    print "sorry, the aninimal you type does not exist"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 a = ["cat","dog","pig","cat"]
    animal = input("enter animal:")

    if animal in a:
        print (animal , "found")
    else:
        print ("animal you entered not found in the list")
```

The above code is apt for your requirement.

Comment: Does your answer add value to the already existing answers (or is your solution significantly different from earlier answers)?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a new way which i am unable to guess how every body missed. We must check string with case insensitive criteria.

```
a = ["cat","dog","fish","hamster"]

user = raw_input("choose your fav pet ")
// adding for user case where user might have entered DOG, but that is valid match
matching_obj = [data for data in a if data.lower() == user.lower()]

if matching_obj:
    print("Data found ",matching_obj)
else:
    print("Data not found")
```