# How To Add More Than one Value In Elif Python?

Tags: python

I am new to Python, and I want to know how can I add more than one value after `==`?

Here is the code:

```
gender = input('Are You Male Or Female ? ')

if gender.capitalize() == 'Male':
    print('You Got 10000 Rs')

elif gender.capitalize() == 'Female':
    print('You Got 5000 Rs')

else:
    print('You Got 1000 Rs')
```

As you can see, the `elif` has `'Female'` after `==`. What if I want to add another value after `'Female'`?

Comment: Look up 'and' and 'or'.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335382/multiple-conditions-with-if-elif-statements

Comment: @SayandipDutta, you're mistaking `capitalize()` and `upper()`. `capitalize()` sets only the first character to be upper-case.

Comment: @SayandipDutta No, `capitalize()` will just convert the first letter to Caps.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use or keyword.

```
    gender = input('Are You Male Or Female ? ')

    if gender.capitalize() == 'Male':
        print('You Got 10000 Rs')

    elif gender.capitalize() == 'Female' or gender.capitalize() == 'Others':
        print('You Got 5000 Rs')

    else:
        print('You Got 1000 Rs')
```

Output:

```
    Are You Male Or Female ? Others
    You Got 5000 Rs
```